API call sequence or priority c#
I dont know how to describe this as a Google search so here it goes..
I have an Azure function with some methods:

POST /123456 -> creates the relation with number 123456 by using the information in the body.

POST / -> creates the relation with a random number by using the information in the body.


Both are handled like this:
[Function("RegisterRelation")]
public async Task<HttpResponseData> RunAsync(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "registerrelation/{relationnumber?}")]

and have a URL Rewrite policy in the API Management Portal:
<rewrite-uri template="/registerrelation/{id}" />

Now I want to have this method as well:

POST /search-> Searches information for a relation by arguments that are specified in the body.

[Function("Searching")]
public async Task<HttpResponseData> RunAsync(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "search")]

I notice that when I run the latter, the first method is executed, (so a relation with number 'search' is created. I believe it is because of the alphabetic order. In .Net6 I was able to fix this with an underscore in the functionname, but .Net8 doesn't accept this anymore..
I will probably make a mistake in the API definition here but I have no clue.

I am able to call both the functions separately by using the below code.
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Net;

namespace _78480784
{
    public class TestFunction
    {
        private readonly ILogger<TestFunction> _logger;

        public TestFunction(ILogger<TestFunction> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("RegisterRelation")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseData> RegisterRelationAsync([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "registerrelation/{relationnumber?}")] HttpRequestData req, string relationnumber)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("RegisterRelation function processed a request.");
            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(relationnumber))
            {
                await response.WriteStringAsync($"Relation Number: {relationnumber}");
            }
            else
            {
                await response.WriteStringAsync("Welcome to Azure Functions! Relation number is not provided.");
            }

            return response;
        }

        [Function("Searching")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseData> SearchingAsync([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "search")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Searching function processed a request.");
            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            await response.WriteStringAsync("Welcome to Search Function!");
            return response;
        }
    }
}

.csproj-
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <RootNamespace>_78480784</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.3-preview1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Output-


Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5700 Commit hash: N/A +71cc84964a60bfb07d95839b7c666bd239507bdd (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.33.2.22572

[2024-05-15T04:42:12.433Z] Found C:\Users\******\78480784\78480784\78480784.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.
[2024-05-15T04:42:16.192Z] Azure Functions .NET Worker (PID: 5296) initialized in debug mode. Waiting for debugger to attach...
[2024-05-15T04:42:16.246Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        RegisterRelation: [POST] http://localhost:7051/api/registerrelation/{relationnumber?}

        Searching: [POST] http://localhost:7051/api/search

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-05-15T04:42:21.328Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000BF6D1ED5'.
[2024-05-15T04:42:40.854Z] Executing 'Functions.Searching' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=1c1c05bf-78e1-4c07-adb9-6d78b1f03c30)
[2024-05-15T04:42:41.218Z] Searching function processed a request.
[2024-05-15T04:42:41.277Z] Executed 'Functions.Searching' (Succeeded, Id=1c1c05bf-78e1-4c07-adb9-6d78b1f03c30, Duration=452ms)
[2024-05-15T04:43:49.740Z] Executing 'Functions.RegisterRelation' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=b8eb8bf0-0333-45b2-a274-a3eaf4351d46)
[2024-05-15T04:43:49.775Z] RegisterRelation function processed a request.
[2024-05-15T04:43:49.784Z] Executed 'Functions.RegisterRelation' (Succeeded, Id=b8eb8bf0-0333-45b2-a274-a3eaf4351d46, Duration=44ms)


I see, but that doesn't explain why in my case this isn't working.

@RobJoosen I tried your approach but it gave me similar signature error, so i update RunAsync in both the cases like RegisterRelationAsync. You can try my code, you will get the output
